# Conditional probability in Galton-Watson

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In discussing Galton-watson chains one considers, for a given generation $n$, iid $\nu$-distributed random variables $x_1^n,\ldots,x_k^n$, where $\nu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$. At some point in the discussion the following equality is used for a fixed positive integer $k$
$$E[\mathbb{1}_{x_1^n+\cdots+x_k^n=k}|\sigma(x_2^n,\ldots,x_n^n)]=\nu(k-x_2^n + \ldots +x_n^n)$$
and I am failing to understand why this equality holds. This is not really specific to Galton Watson, it was just to give a reference of where this comes from.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y) \, | \, \sigma(X)] = \mathbb{E}[h(x,Y)]\rvert_{x=X}$.

Comment: Hi @Furrer. Yes I tried to justify it with that formula, but if I set $Y=x_2^n+\cdots+x_k^n$, $X=x_1^n$, $h=\mathbb{1}_{x_1^n+\cdots+x_k^n=k}$, I get, as a lhs of your expression $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{1}_{x=k - x_k^n - \cdots x_2^n} \nu(x)$.

Comment: For which values of $x$ is the indicator not zero? What does this tell you about the sum?

Comment: Oops. apologies.

Comment: No worries. I hope everything is clear to you now? I gave some more details on the identity in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argument based on conditional distributions goes as follow. Let $(P_x)$ be a regular conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y) \, | \, X = x]
=
\int h(x,y) \, P_x(\mathrm{d}y)
\end{align*}
cf. Theorem 2.2.3 in the following excellent lecture notes: http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/beting.pdf. (Similar results also appear in standard textbook references on the subject.) If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then one may take $P_x$ to be $Y(\mathbb{P})$, and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y) \, | \, X = x]
=
\int h(x,y) Y(\mathbb{P})(\mathrm{d}y)
=
\mathbb{E}[h(x,Y)].
\end{align*}
Thus $\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y) \, | \, X] = \mathbb{E}[h(x,Y)]\rvert_{x=X}$. Alternatively, one may show that the latter expression satisfies the conditions of being the desired conditional expectation.

The result now follows by choosing $X$, $Y$, and $h$ appropriately, as we discussed in the comments.